# Конфликт версий GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Есть шейдер в котором используется встроенная переменная `gl_PointCoord`.
На десктопе компилятор говорит, что для того чтобы использовать эту переменную, необходимо указать версию шейдера 120+. Хорошо, указываю: `#version 120`
Но на андроиде (OpenGL ES 2.0) компилятор говорит, что не знает 120 версию языка. При этом поддержка
`gl_PointCoord` в ES 2.0 и так есть. По идее для десктопа я должен указывать версию языка, а для андроид нет.
Но как это сделать?

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#else
#version 120
#endif
```

Такой вариант отказывается компилироваться по причине  `error C0204: version directive must be first statement`

Вот такая дилемма. Шейдер работает либо не десктопе, либо на андроид, в зависимости от того, укажу я версию или нет.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PointCoord.xhtml + https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_PointCoord.xhtml просто сделайте 2 версии шейдера.

Comment: @こきん Если не найдется более элегантного решения, так и сделаю.

Comment: Можете попробовать дописывать "шапку" к шейдеру на этапе его загрузки, в зависимости от платформы.

Comment: Видимо на десктопе вы работаете с OpenGL, а на андроиде - с OpenGL ES. Вполне вероятно, что для них придется делать два (или больше) разных шейдера.